# How to return records by comparing two tables even one of it have empty or null value in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am having two tables namely X and Y.I have to get the records of X table by comparing the id of X.id which is not equal to Y.id? 
It is working fine when 'Y table' have records to match with 'X'.If there is no records(i.e empty or null value) in Y table,then X also returns null...

And how do i handle this null and get the X table records?

```
SELECT X.id,
       X.company_Id 
FROM X,Y 
WHERE X.status_Id = 9 
AND X.active=1 
AND X.company_Id IN (SELECT Company_Id 
                     FROM Z
                     WHERE user_Id =1 
                     AND association_Id=1) 
AND X.id <> Y.id
```

Please help me to find the solution.

Comment: I think you can use join type: LEFT JOIN

Comment: learn how to use LEFT join.

Comment: Perhaps [this article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) will help, it has a visual explanation of different joins that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    X.id,
    X.company_Id
FROM
    x
    LEFT JOIN y   /*<<<<<<<<<<<*/
WHERE
    X.status_Id = 9
    AND X.active = 1
    AND X.company_Id IN (
        SELECT
            Company_Id
        FROM
            Z
        WHERE
            user_Id = 1
        AND
            association_Id = 1)
    AND X.id <> Y.id
```

By using left join, you get all the rows in X, even the ones where x.id didn't match Y.id, then the where clause eliminates Rows where X.id = Y.id

Comment: Thank you.But already tried this one too.It returns from Y table also.My requirement is to get only mismatch records.

Comment: your requirement is not clear. what's the relationship between x and y? can you show some sample data?

Comment: select e.enquiry_id,e.company_Id from enquiry e 
LEFT JOIN enquiry_query ei ON (e.enquiry_id = ei.enquiry_id)
where e.status_Id=9 and 
e.active=1 and e.company_Id in (SELECT company_id FROM users
where userId =1 and association_Id=1) and e.enquiry_id<> ei.enquiry_id

Comment: I want to return only mismatch data from both the tables.If it is null value in enquiry_query table,have to return the present records from enquiry table.